# Kivy run sound interface along with GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

So i have a simple kivy window that I build using MainApp().run() as per the official documentation.

I also want to include some interface using my voice and I have created a separate class for controlling the flow.

```
from modules import speech

class Interface:
    def start(self):
        s = speech.Speech("mirror mirror on the wall", "thank you mirror")
        while True:
            while not s.check_launch_phrase():
                s.speak()
            print("You gained access")
            while not s.check_close_phrase():
                s.speak()
                print("decide action")
```

And this is my Speech module:

```
import speech_recognition as sr

class Speech():
    def __init__(self, launch_phrase, close_phrase):
        self._launch_phrase = launch_phrase
        self._close_phrase = close_phrase
        self._r = sr.Recognizer()
        self._audio = None
        self._text = ""

    def get_text(self):
        return self._text

    def _listen_for_audio(self):
        m = sr.Microphone()
        with m as source:
            self._r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)
            print("Listening...")
            self._audio = self._r.listen(source, phrase_time_limit=5)

    def _speech_to_text(self):
        try:
            self._text = self._r.recognize_google(self._audio)
        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            self._text = ""
            print("I could not understand you")

    def check_launch_phrase(self):
        if self._text == self._launch_phrase:
            return True
        return False

    def check_close_phrase(self):
        if self._text == self._close_phrase:
            return True
        return False

    def speak(self):
        self._listen_for_audio()
        self._speech_to_text()
        print(self._text)
```

Now in my main.py file I have the following code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    interface = Interface()
    SmartMirrorApp().run()
    interface.start()
```

The problem is that first it opens the window and after I close the window the interface starts running.

Is there any way to run them concurrently or do I need to utilize threads?

P.S. The SmartMirrorApp() can be any basic kivy window for testing.

Comment: You need to use threading otherwise the GUI will freeze

Comment: The `SmartMirrorApp().run()` does not return until the `App` is shut down.

Comment: Can I just use the `threading` module or do I need to change anything in my kivy app as well?